# Java - JTabbedPane - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when adding a new panel

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a weird problem using a `JTabbedPane` and adding a new tab to it.

```
public void addTab(String title, AbstractTab tab) {
    int i = tabPanel.getTabCount();
    System.out.println("Tab count:" + i);
    tab.validate();
    tabPanel.insertTab(title, null, tab, title, i);
    tabPanel.validate();
    tabPanel.setSelectedIndex(i);
}
```

Running this code causes the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.getTitleAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.updateHtmlViews(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.componentAdded(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processContainerEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.insertTab(Unknown Source)
at View.Swing.Global.**EditorPanel.addTab(EditorPanel.java:383)**
at View.Swing.Developer.DeveloperContentPanel.showNote(DeveloperContentPanel.java:176)
at View.Swing.Developer.DeveloperTreeViewer.clickedTreeElement(DeveloperTreeViewer.java:62)
at View.Swing.Global.TreeNavigation.mouseClicked(TreeNavigation.java:556)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
...
```

The  `System.out.println(..);`  prints

```
Tab count 1
```

The weird thing is, that this method works once, and another time it throws this exception. The added tabs are instances of the class `AbstractTab`, containing `JTextFields`, a `MetaphaseEditor`, scrollbars, `JLabels` and `JTextArea`s and some pictures (`ImageIcon`).

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Comment: You may not have enough information here to allow us to give an answer. Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) -- a small compilable and runnable program that we can run within need of outside resources and that demonstrates your problem. Also, I think that the word you're looking for is "weird".

Comment: Why don't you use `addTab()` and `setSelectedComponent()`? Then you don't need to care about the index.

Answer (score 2):

from [Bugtracker](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4176095), maybe you use a component more than once?

> Clarify in documentation that no 2 tabs in a JTabbedPane can have the
> same component assigned to them.. causes
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 > 0

Comment: +1 for the good idea :-) though when doing so, the actual stacktrace is a bit different from the one shown above (IndexOOB in JTabbedPane.checkIndex)